# lxsession-logout vs lxde-logout

Tags: ubuntu, users, session, lubuntu

I'm new with lxde, I installed it on ubuntu 14.04 using `sudo apt-get install lxde.` But the problem I have is that I want to logout without a prompt. I've read some articles about this and they suggested one of these: `lxsession-logout or lxde-logout`. But they cannot be used to logout without a prompt. The question is what are the main differences between them? Is it possible to logout without a prompt on lxde? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`lxde-logout` is just a wrapper to `lxsession-logout`.  It's a simple script

```
% cat /usr/bin/lxde-logout 
#!/bin/sh
lxsession-logout --banner "/usr/share/lxde/images/logout-banner.png" --side=top
```

http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1731 claims you can just send a SIGTERM to `lxsession` and the PID should be in `$_LXSESSION_PID`.

So

```
kill -TERM $_LXSESSION_PID
```

Comment: thank you very much for response. But is there any other way then sending SIGTERM to logout without a prompt?

Comment: I've tried using dbus `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 --dest=org.lxde.SessionManager /org/lxde/SessionManager org.lxde.SessionManager.Logout` but it didn't work, it doesnt give me any errors but still doesnt logout